# How Ignite stores the value on heap

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

I am thinking of using the Data grid feature that Ignite provides. I am not clear about one aspect of Apache Ignite.

I wanted to know that whenever I put an object into an Ignite Cache ( which stores entries only on heap as no off heap is enabled ), does it serialize the object and stores it on the heap or does it stores the object as it is?

If I access the stored value from a process ( using IgniteCache#get ) running on the same JVM ( whose Heap the Ignite Value is stored in ), will Ignite first De-serialize the value and then give to my process ?

If the answer to the question is yes, then I would like to know that is there a workaround wherein I can bypass the overhead of serialization to improve the performance of my cache gets?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite stores values in binary format and by default value is deserialized each time you read it.

If you set `CacheConfiguration.copyOnRead`, deserialized value will be shared along with binary form. This can increase read performance, but will also increase memory consumption. Also you should avoid mutating objects read this way.

Another option to avoid deserialization is to use `withKeepBinary()` flag. When set, cache will return `BinaryObject` instance instead of deserialized object. Refer to this page for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

Comment: If I make use of Binary Marshaller I would still have to perform deserialization to get the value as an object?

Comment: All described above applies to any marshaller (except `withKeepBinary()` of course, which is unique for `BinaryMarshaller`).